# Is there a function to redirect spec. users to the dashboard.php page after login?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, authentication, redirect

Im trying to redirect the users (not admin) to the dashboard.php page after login.
**What I did:** I've copied the function below in my functions.php and the shortcode in the new-login page.
**What happend:** I see the login form in the new-login page but cannot log in (nothing happend when I push the submit button).
**Spec:** Im using woocommerce plugin.
• Is there a function (to redirect the users to the dashboard.php page after login) can works with the function below or is wrong? I need to use a different function?

```
// Custom Login 
function uilogin_func( $args ) {
  $a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'echo' => true,
    'remember' => true,
    'redirect' => ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
    'form_id' => 'loginform',
    'id_username' => 'user_login',
    'id_password' => 'user_pass',
    'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
    'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
    'label_username' => __( 'Username or Email Address' ),
    'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
    'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
    'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
    'value_username' => '',
    'value_remember' => false
  ), $args );
  wp_login_form( $a );
}
add_shortcode( 'uilogin', 'uilogin_func' );
```

Comment: hi i cant understand what you mean but this site may be help you to fix this problem https://appsepid.ir/project-order/

Answer (score 1):

Generally in PHP the way to do a redirect from the server would be to (after your login validation) would be to [set the header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). However, since you mention WooCommerce and have a specific set of user permissions within framework you are using, set up your site normally you can use this plugin for the "After Login" function of [this workflow](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/redirect-after-login-registration-logout/#prettyPhoto/1/).

Comment: I have to say that 2021 starts well, I also accidentally found a function I was looking for like `function add_login_check()
{
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        if (is_page(85)){
            wp_redirect('https://mywebsite.net/dashboard/');
            exit; 
        }
    }
}
`  Now I just need to redirect (new-login page) users who try to login on wp-login. Just an opinion, is my overall way correct? Or is it complicated?

Comment: I suppose this would work: you would probably have a reference dictionary which would contain the redirect logic